# Import demo data into wordpress template

Tags: import

I have wordpress template from themeforest and I would like to set it up, just like demo page on themeforest....

I found files like customizer.dat.txt, demo=content.xml, widgets.json ...

they probably serve for this purpose but as I'm newbie in Wordpress, have no idea how to use them.

Can you please help me how to import ? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

After installing all required plugins of theme.
goto tool->import install wordpress importer plugin then import your content.xml file.
Also you can find all information inside theme documentation.

Comment: ok this worked well, but the page on demo looks like one page website, but on my web I still see page which looks like blog. The template has several sections, which I can edit directly in wp-menu, but I cant see anything on front-end. Can you help me ?

Comment: goto settings-> readings and select the page which you want to show on the front. If still problem exists then you can give me temporary access to your site i'll set it up for you once.

Comment: the template has also some option "One Click Demo Import". I've pressed it but page continously loads something ....I probably need to put above files somewhere in webside. Do you know something about it ? ... PS: thank you for your offer

Comment: can't tell more without watching the interface of your template. But these files have nothing to with the theme these are only for import they don't need to put any where inside theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you already install the theme just go to the tools>import then you can see a list of importer.just click on wordpress, after installing the plugin
click on run importer then simple choose your demo.xml file, then click on upload file and import

hope it will be helpful for you :)